# Language Packs not needed offered for update again+again

Tags: updates, language

I have been using eOS for more than a year now and I am happy with it. Great systems. Congrats to the developers.

I am getting updates offered for probably all languages spoken anywhere on the world again and again. As I live in Switzerland I have the settings language=german, formats=swiss.
Each time I unselect these dozens of languages I do not want on my system and I never selected or installed anywhere. With the only result that I get a notification right away after the remaining updates are installed that more updates (guess what: dozens of language packs) are wating for installation.

This is kind of ridiculous. Is there no option that updates once rejected should not be offered again?

Greetings
Ulrich

Answer (score 1):

I have been researching about your problem and finally found a plausible explanation:

"A package only gets updates if it is installed, so if the languages are updated, they must be installed somehow. 
To manage installed packages in a detailed way, Synaptic is a convenient tool. 
You can install Synaptic from the Software Center (or by the command sudo apt-get install synaptic). 
Then, in Synaptic, search for the packages and remove them if you are sure you don't need them."

Source: https://askubuntu.com/questions/556101/how-to-prevent-unnecessary-updates/556149#556149